# How do I use the JavaScript string replace method to replace the '+' sign?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, global

All you need to know is in the question. I have a search query in the URL that looks like this:

http://www.mysite.com?param=word1+word2+word3

So far, I can retrieve "word1+word2+word3" but I can't seem to use something like:

```
document.write(str.replace(/+/g," "));
```

I want the final output to look like this: "word1 word2 word3"

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to escape the `+` sign using the escape char `\` since is a restricted char:

```
document.write(str.replace(/\+/g," "));
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: Thanks. I am glad the answer was helpful and fast :)

Comment: Thanks everyone, and mazzucci for being first :)

Answer (score 2):

The `+` is a special character in regex, if you want to match it literally you have to escape it. So try:

```
document.write(str.replace(/\+/g," "));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the `+` sign, it's has special meaning in Regexes.

```
document.write(str.replace(/\+/g," "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the hex value

```
document.write(str.replace(/[\u002B]/g," "));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [`split()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function, that seems to be much simpler for this case:

```
document.write(str.split(",", " ");
```